# Extracting information from an XML php gives me error

Tags: php, xml, streaming

I need to extract information from an XML Radionomy (radio streaming) containing information of artist, title, cover art, weather etc.

By placing this url in the browser goes all information xml:

```
http://api.radionomy.com/currentsong.cfm?radiouid=ce5b70e5-dcc3-40a2-81b2-c713a02daf29&apikey=842650d9-c21a-474d-be8f-f44413dfaae2&callmeback=no&type=xml&cover=yes&previ%20ous=no

<tracks>
<radioname>RTFM</radioname>
<rank>2</rank>
<isradionomy>1</isradionomy>
<radurl>http://www.radionomy.com/rtfm</radurl>
<track>
<uniqueid>2905480252</uniqueid>
<title>02-13-2016</title>
<artists>News - US</artists>
<starttime>2016-02-14 00:59:57.177</starttime>
<playduration>121352</playduration>
<current>1</current>
</track>
</tracks>
```

But to try to get information through php gives me error. I do not know where he might be the problem, see if I can lend a hand.

I'm trying this:

```
$xml = @simplexml_load_file("
http://api.radionomy.com/currentsong.cfm?radiouid=ce5b70e5-dcc3-40a2-81b2-c713a02daf29&apikey=842650d9-c21a-474d-be8f-f44413dfaae2&callmeback=no&type=xml&cover=yes&previ%20ous=no");


if($xml){


foreach ($xml as $track){



$artiste = $track->artists;
$titre = $track->title;
$pochette = $track->cover;

continue;

}

}else{

    echo "error";

    }
```

**Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in...**

Comment: Please see the description and provided working code I send in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

Noticed more mistakes and provided working code.

Use urlencode to encode your URL string. Use $xml->track to loop track nodes.

And stop using @ to see the actual errors. It is really helpful to see errors.

Didn't touch your original code but you can take it from here.

```
<?php

$xml = simplexml_load_file(urlencode("http://api.radionomy.com/currentsong.cfm?radiouid=ce5b70e5-dcc3-40a2-81b2-c713a02daf29&apikey=842650d9-c21a-474d-be8f-f44413dfaae2&callmeback=no&type=xml&cover=yes&previ%20ous=no"));

if($xml){

    foreach ($xml->track as $track){

        $artiste = $track->artists;
        $titre = $track->title;
        $pochette = $track->cover;

        continue;
    }
} else {
     echo "error";
}
```

Comment: Yesssssss is amazing, has been using this method and running instantly. You're great, thank you very much !!

Comment: Glad to hear it helped. Please consider "not" using @ and let errors to be revealed - unless it is really necessary.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll remember: D